# how to redirect user to the home page after login details on submit button click

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Am trying to direct a user to admin dashboard after login if user name and password exist in the database. if not then direct user back to the login page. But is not working when the user enters his details instead of going to the admin dashboard page it is directed back to the login page even though users details are in the database. The problem is with the admin-dashboard.php file if I comment out "header('location:index.php');" it works perfectly but user can access the admin-dashboard without logging in form the url search bar and i don't want that way

This is my index.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   header('location:admin-dashboard.php');
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login | Admin</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.css"/> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="css/text">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<style type="text/css">
html,body{
    height:100%;

}
</style>
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="card border-danger shadow-lg">
                    <div class="card-header bg-danger">
                        <h3 class="m-0 text-white"><i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>&nbsp;Admin Panel Login</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="action" method="post" class="px-3 " id="admin-login-form"> 
                            <div id="adminLoginAlert"></div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control 
                                form-control-lg rounded-2" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control 
                                form-control-lg rounded-2" placeholder="Password" autocomplete= required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" name="admin-login" class="btn btn-danger
                                btn-block btn-lg rounded-2" value="Login" id="adminLoginBtn">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
// sending ajax request to server
    $("#adminLoginBtn").click(function(e){
    if($("#admin-login-form")[0].checkValidity()){
            e.preventDefault();
                $(this).val('Please Wait...');
                $.ajax({
                    url:'assets/php/admin-action.php',
                    method:'post',
                    data:$("#admin-login-form").serialize()+'&action=adminLogin',
                    success:function(response){
                        if($.trim(response) == 'register'){
                            window.location = 'admin-dashboard.php';
                        }
                        
                        if(response === 'admin_login'){
                            window.location = 'admin-dashboard.php';
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#adminLoginAlert").html(response);
                        }
                        $("#adminLoginBtn").val('Login');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My admin-dashboard.php

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   header('location:index.php'); 
   exit();
  
}
?>
<a href="assets/php/logout.php">Logout</a>
```

My config.php

```
  <?php
class Database {
    
    private $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_user_system";
    private $dbuser = "root";
    private $dbpass = "";

    public $conn;

    public function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO($this->dsn,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass);
               
              

        }catch (PDOExeception $e) {
            echo 'Error :'.$e->getMessage();

        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
    // Checking Input 
    public function test_input($data){
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    // Error success message alert
    public function showMessage($type,$message){
        return '<div class="alert alert-'.$type.' alert-dismissible "> 
                    <button type="button" class="close" 
                    data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong class="text-center"> '.$message.' </strong>
                    
                     </div>';
    }

    
}




?>
```

My logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
header('location:../../index.php'); 


?>
```

My admin-action.php

```
    <?php
require_once 'admin-db.php';

$admin = new Admin();

    // Handle admin login ajax Request

if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'adminLogin'){
    $username = $admin->test_input($_POST['username']);
    $password =$admin->test_input($_POST['password']);


    $hpassword = sha1($password);
    $loggedInAdmin = $admin->admin_login($username,$hpassword);

    if($loggedInAdmin !=null){
        echo 'admin_login';
        $_SESSION['username']= $username;
    }
    else {
      echo  $admin->showMessage('danger', 'Username or Password is Incorrect!');}
    }

    ?>
```

My admin-db.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

//creating new object of admin class in admin-action.php
class Admin extends Database {
    // Admin login

    public function admin_login($username, $password)
    {
       $sql = "SELECT username,password FROM admin WHERE username = :username AND 
       password = :password";

       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->execute(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password]);
       $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

       return $row; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this academic code purely for learning or for a production site?

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: is for a production site

Comment: Trash this code. Don't even think about using it on a production site. Build on an existing framework that has a field-tested authentication system. The risks are simply way too high. For example, you use SHA1 which is completely inappropriate for password hashing. *Focus on building your application, not re-inventing the wheel.*

Comment: I do not get you pertaining to storing password as plain text and what do suggest I used for the password hashing

Comment: Use an existing system. Do not use your own homebrew method. Never store passwords as plain-text. There's a lot more than just password hashing. There's a long, long list of concerns.

Comment: Do not use `test_input()`. It will damage your data.

Comment: This certainly does not look like a production-ready code. If you are doing this for learning then you should stop, and unlearn it. Please research basic security principles first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need your location header to be an absolute path with HTTP 1.1 as specified in the PHP documentation. `header('Location: http://localhost/admin-dashboard.php');` or call within exit, `exit(header('Location: http://localhost/admin-dashboard.php'));`

See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

First of all fetch data from the database
if the result is greater than 0
it redirects with the below code

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

//creating new object of admin class in admin-action.php
class Admin extends Database {
    // Admin login

    public function admin_login($username, $password)
    {
       $sql = "SELECT username,password FROM admin WHERE username = :username AND 
       password = :password";

       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->execute(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password]);
       $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($row > 0){
header('location:index.php);
}else{
header('location:error.php);
}

  }
}
?>
```